# How to change Mesh Primitive Node's color when animation?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, color, geometry

I'm using the key-frame to make an animation but I couldn't figure out how to change the cube's color. I just need the cube to be a static color.

- OS: Linux mint 20.3 Cinnamon
- Blender Version: 3.2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the node `Set Material`:

[image]

This assigns a previously created material to a geometry created in *Geometry Nodes*.

Comment: Many Thanks. I searched almost everywhere but couldn't find the right answer.